# Quantum tunnelling in semiconductors

Tags: semiconductor-physics, quantum-tunneling

Is quantum tunnelling is possible in a semiconductor (that is on either sides of depletion region)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and indeed this is exploited in the construction of [tunnel diodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunnel_diode). However in normal diodes the depletion region is too wide for any significant tunnelling current to flow.